# Python comparing strings

Tags: python, string

I have a code where in I first convert a .csv file into multiple lists and then I have to create a subset of the original file containing only those with a particular word in column 5 of my file.

I am trying to use the following code to do so, but it gives me a syntax error for the if statement.  Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

```
import csv
with open('/Users/jadhav/Documents/Hubble files/m4_hubble_1.csv') as f:
    bl = [[],[],[],[],[]]
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for r in reader:
        for c in range(5):
            bl[c].append(r[c])

    print "The files have now been sorted into lists"
    name = 'HST_10775_64_ACS_WFC_F814W_F606W'
    for c in xrange(0,1):
        if bl[4][c]!='HST_10775_64_ACS_WFC_F814W_F606W' 
            print bl[0][c]
```

Comment: Hint: you are missing a `:` character..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a colon after your if test, and you need to indent the if taken clause:

```
if bl[4][c]!='HST_10775_64_ACS_WFC_F814W_F606W':
    print bl[0][c]
```

Comment: Indentation problems on SO are usually caused by the poster not knowing [how to format code blocks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).